# Wordpress theme force footer to bottom of page for short content pages

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm editing a wordpress theme. I can't seem to get the footer div to stick to the bottom of the page when there's not a lot of page content. example here:

```
http://openstrings.co.uk/?page_id=148
```

I've read loads of tutorials about a wrapper with min-height: 100% and a negative height to match the height of the footer. But I can't get anything to work. I can't see that there is a wrapper div that I can apply CSS to?

Would appreciate any pointers. Have tried footer with bottom:0px and body min-height:100% but  still not forcing the footer down.

Comment: Do you need to support IE8 or lower?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number places that outline how to do this sort of thing (and lots of answers that work better or worse with different browsers) but here's one that may help:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com

Be aware that you may not be able to SIMPLY edit the CSS, but may need to edit the themes HTML template as well to ensure that the wrapper div exists.

Comment: yeah I can see that a wrapper doesn't exist. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The cheapest trick in the book is to make the background color of your entire site (body tag) the footer color, and then add another tag "wrapper" that has background color white or whatever you want.

```
<body style="background-color:black">
 <div class="wrapper" style="background-color:white">

   //WEBSITE CONTENT

 </div>

</body>
```